# Declaring a variable dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I need some variables in the following format:

```
$m_01;
$m_02;
$m_03;
.....
.....
.....
$m_12;
```

The digits in the variables are the months of the calendar.
I can declare 12 variables separately. However, I want to declare the variable using a loop. So I did something like this.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if($i<10)
        $month = '0'.$i;
    else
        $month = $i;
    $m_$i;
}
```

However, I am getting some error:-

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$month' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/custom/ci/Dotell_customer/application/controllers/login.php on line 412

How can I overcome this issue?

**NOTE:**

```
$$month creates a variable 01;
```

Is there any way where I can cave variable `m_01`?

**P.S. I am aware of array. I just want to learn PHP variables variables.**

Comment: What you're looking for is an "array".

Comment: You can also try [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: While @David is right, you can (but shouldn't) use ${'m_'.$i};`

Comment: @Saswat, can you comment on David question on why you are not using array? Is the intent to learn about the PHP variables variable or you are not just aware about the PHP arrays?

Answer (score 5):

This is not the best practise to follow, but still just for the answer:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
     ${"m_$i"} = $i;
}

echo $m_1;
echo $m_2;
echo $m_3;
```

The best practise would be to create an array. For eg:

```
$arr = [];
for( $i=0; $i <=12; $i++ ) {
    $arr['m_'.$i] = $i;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: and why are you suggesting it when it's not the best?

Comment: there are uses of variables variable. I am not sure if OP has just shown this as an example to see how this can be done.

Comment: Because it provides insights to the nuances of php while being a functional solution to the problem given.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like

```
$varname = 'm_'.$i; // format the way you need it

$$varname = ...
```

As noted in the comments, it's rather a code smell, and often unnecessary. Typically an array does a better job, i.e.

```
$m[$i] = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP variable variables. This works as also suggested in the comments

```
${"m_$i"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with Davids suggestion of using an array.

```
$month = [];

for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    if($i<10)
        $month[] = '0'.$i;
    else
        $month[] = $i;
    $month[$i];
}
```

here the $var[] = ... syntax appends your array. the $month[$i] accesses it.

Answer (score 0):

Use of double variable is not usually suggested. You should really use an array to solve your problem as:

```
$month = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    if($i<10)
        $month['m_0'.$i] = $i;
    else
        $month['m_'.$i] = $i;
}
```

otherwise if you really want to necessary go for double variable then :

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    if($i<10)
        ${"m_0$i"} = $i;
    else
        ${"m_$i"} = $i;
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score -2):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    if($i<10)
        $month = '0'.$i;
    else
        $month = $i;

     $month = 'm_' . $month;
     ..........
}
```

Access var as

assignment $month = 'm_12';

value `$$month`